# Authorize actions on nested resources

Tags: activeadmin

Suppose I have a Project model and a Task model. Tasks belong to Projects, and projects have an "active" flag.

```rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active?
    false # always false, for simplicity
  end
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

My ActiveAdmin config looks like this:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Project

ActiveAdmin.register Task do
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Finally, I have an Authorizer, in which I would like to authorize the user to create new Tasks on Projects if the user is a project owner. Otherwise, users should not be authorized to create new Tasks on inactive Projects.

The challenge I am running into is that in the `TasksController#index` action, the value of `subject` in my Authorizer is `Task` (the class) and not an instance, and I'm not able to access the instance of the parent Project, even though one is known based on the URL `/projects/123/tasks`.

Even though the current view is an index, and there is no Task instance, there should be a parent Project instance to which the current list of Tasks is scoped.

How can I access this parent Project instance in my Authorizer so I can examine its `#active?` flag?

```rb
class Authorizer < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter
  def authorized?(action, subject)
    case subject
    when Task
      # how can I access the parent Project instance here?
      # project owners always have full access
      return true if project.owner == current_user

      # all users have read access
      return true if action == :read

      # non-owners may create tasks if the project is active
      return parent_project.active? if action == :create
        

      # non-owners may update and delete tasks on active projects;
      # :update and :destroy are instance actions and thus the subject will be
      # an instance of Task that we can traverse to the project
      subject.project.active?

    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```